Who are the characters seen in their prison cells as G.I. Robot is escorted to his cell in "Creature Commandos"?
In Creature Commandos Season 1, Episode 3, "Cheers to the Tin Man," a flashback shows G.I. Robot being escorted to his prison cell in Belle Reve Penitentiary.
During this scene, we see other inmates in their cells, presumably all DC Comics supervillains: a hooded figure with a metal gauntlet and shoulder piece, a hairy, bearded individual, Animal-Vegetable-Mineral Man, and the Crimson Centipede (as identified in a Collider article).


Who are the hooded prisoner and the hairy, bearded prisoner?
